# Dimension of the space of solutions to the differential equation $x' = Ax$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

I have no idea where to begin this proof.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you know about the Jordan form of matrices, you can replace $A$ by a simpler matrix and start from there for an explicit resolution.

For a more theoretical argument, you certainly have some kind of Cauchy-Lipschitz theorem at your disposal to deal with the matter.

Answer (score 0):

For a proof that can be easily extended to a more general case [Cauchy-Lipschitz theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem)
ensures that

$$\forall x_0 \exists!\ \varepsilon>0,\ f:[0,\varepsilon)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n\ s.t.\ \begin{cases}\frac{df}{dt}=Af\\ f(0)=x_0\end{cases}$$

Now, let $e_i$ the canonical (or even *any*) base of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Let $f_i$ such as above, with $f_i(0)=e_i$

You may easily show that, in a sufficiently smal neightborhood of $t=0$:

- $\{f_i\}_1^n$ are independent as functions
- $\begin{cases}\frac{df}{dt}=Af\\ f(0)=\sum_{i=1}^n a_ie_i\end{cases}$ is solved by $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i f_i$